# 553 Could not create file. && 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

Стоит задача: используя терминал Ubuntu, передать какой либо файл по локальной сети используя утилиту `vsftpd` со своего компьютера на удаленный, будучи анонимным ftp-пользователем.

Файл для передачи - выбрал сжатую папку с игрой `Angels.of.Death.zip`

Домашняя папка для анонимного пользователя `/media/reiji/1F3B910146CE45A7/anime`

Папка в которой я нахожусь во время выполения команды `ftp -a 192.168.0.32` это - `/media/reiji/1F3B910146CE45A7`

Вывод команды `l` в папке `/media/reiji/1F3B910146CE45A7` -

```
Angels.of.Death.zip*  anime/
```

`ls -l` для `Angels.of.Death.zip`:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 reiji reiji 1010334063 мар 29 18:50 Angels.of.Death.zip
```

Мои раскомментированные значения в файле `/etc/vsftpd.conf` -

```
listen=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES

anon_upload_enable=YES

anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

[Здесь](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ftp) сказано

> Similarly, by default, anonymous users are not allowed to upload files to FTP server. To change this setting, you should uncomment the following line, and restart vsftpd:

> `anon_upload_enable=YES`

В соответствии с вышесказанным установил значение `anon_upload_enable=YES`.
Так же перед этим значением был такой комментарий:

```
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
```

В соответствии с этим комментарием я устанавливаю права доступа на `755`, и получаю при попытке установить соединение ошибку `500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()` - по сути дав FTP-пользователю права на запись. Лишив FTP-пользователя права записывать в домашнюю папку (`555`), соединение с FTP-сервером устанавливается нормально, но перестает работать команда `put Angels.of.Death.zip` так как у указанного пользователя нет прав на запись в папке `/media/reiji/1F3B910146CE45A7/anime`, и тут я уже получаю ошибку `553 Could not create file.`.

*Вопрос:* **как выполнить поставленную в начале текста задачу если одни права доступа противоречат другим???**

Comment: Слушай, а тебе обязательно ftp нужен? Другие протоколы не подойдут? У тебя лаба или реальная задача?

Comment: @donRumata, вообще честно говоря мне то же самое сказали на `askubuntu.com` и предложили альтернативы использующие SSH типа SCP & SFTP. И решение своей задачи я уже осуществляю на SCP. Но вопрос ПОЧЕМУ такое противоречие происходит остался открытым. Я прекрасно понимаю что люди которые писали `vsftpd` это явно не новички - а значит каких-то знаний уже не хватает мне. Я грешил на то что домашняя папка которую я меняю через `sudo usermod -d /media/reiji/1F3B910146CE45A7 ftp` по факту не меняется. Но как проверить это я тоже не знаю.

Comment: @donRumata, опечатался `sudo usermod -d /media/reiji/1F3B910146CE45A7/anime ftp`

Comment: Я юзаю vsftpd только для того, чтобы раздавать музло и кинцо со своего винта в интернет. Для перекидывания между своими тачками - `sshfs`, `samba`, `rsync`, `croc`. Т.е. мой сервак в принципе не настроен на то, чтобы в него логинились или чё-то через него писали. Только отдача контента всем кто зайдёт. Никаких пользователей, ничего. Всё шикарно пашет.